# java object overlap or memory corruption

Tags: java, memory, redis, log4j

I have a running application on jdk8. it is behaving weirdly. For instance, if I call to redis for a key, some times getting response of other key.I am object pool for jedis objects. Some times I see log messages are getting corrupted, i.e part of log message is getting written into application.

Initially i have thought of app did not restart properly.I have tried restarting application, it did work on few nodes/servers and not on other servers.

I have tried running same war in in different node and did put pressure on application with loadtest tool but i did not see any such issue even i run it for 24 hours

Specifically, I have these questions:

1. Is it jvm malfunctioning because, I see something related to object
       overlap, I mean here getting values of one object to other?
2. Is there a way that I can see the values and its memory allocations
   in runtime

Comment: Sounds like a tough problem. But what is your question? You see, there is probably a bug in your code or setup. Or multiple of them. There is even a (really small) chance that you actually hit a jvm bug. But what do you think we could do for you? You have logs, you know the code base, you know your setup. You have direct access to anything that matters to debug such problems. We have nothing but what you wrote in your question. Seriously: what is your expectation now?

Comment: Sorry @GhostCat, i have updated my question. Please check it once

Comment: Your edit really doesn't help much. *I see something related to object overlap, I mean here getting* ... again, nothing what you say here is clear enough to give you sound advice. *Is there a way that I can see the values and its memory allocations in runtime* ... sure, that is what debuggers are for. But again: this is all too broad. This community can do a good job with code that fits into a single question. What you need is a person with a lot of experience in debugging such java systems ... who sits in front of the machine.